# Can I wrap a whole page in a div to move it down a few pixels without breaking it's complex layout?

Tags: html, css, position

I have to add a small banner at the top of a page and am having trouble with pushing the existing content down 40px so I can fit in the banner above.

The current layout has a lot of strangley positioned elements and they all keep moving out of place if I wrap the whole body area in a relative block div with a top margin.

Is there a technique that should work for this other than wrapping in a div like this?

Comment: Can you not put top padding on the `<body>` or just insert the element and have it push down the contents below? What is so complicated about your layout that it is causing these to not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this, then you have to be careful that your CSS positioning on the divs that you want to move is not absolute. Because if it is, then they will just stay where they are. It should however, work if you add a div that encompasses everything and put a few pixels of padding on the top with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put a  at the top of the page and set that div to clear:both afterwards. This should shift the rest of the page down 40px, or whatever you set the height of that div to. Of course, I'm just guessing here without looking at code and/or a sample site. Since I assume by strangely positioned you mean weird usage of position:absolute, this should allow your current setup to remain consistent.